# UITableViewCell height wont update after adding a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell to which I am adding a subview to. However, after I add the subview, the height of the cell still reports the old height from before I added the subview.

```
    // Setting up using rx, calling cell.setup()
    viewModel
        .map { $0.viewModels }
        .flatMap(ignoreNil)
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "TableViewCell", cellType: TableViewCell.self)) { (row, viewModel, cell) in
            cell.viewModel = viewModel
            cell.setup()
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

// Cell setup in my UITableViewCell class
private func setup() {
     let threeTileView = TileView(frame: bodyView.bounds)

      // Bodyview is a view within the cell
      bodyView.addSubview(threeTileView)
    }
```

The bodyview is also disappearing when it scrolls offscreen because I am guessing theres some layout issue with adding the subview to my cell. My tableview doesnt recognize the view added to bodyView and only registers the other views in my cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
 let threeTileView = TileView(frame: bodyView.bounds)
```

frame-layout won't update the height of the tableCell , you have to use auto-layout for that because `bodyView`'s bounds isn't yet correctly calculated

//

```
bodyView.addSubview(threeTileView)
threeTileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false   
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    threeTileView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyView.leadingAnchor),
    threeTileView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyView.trailingAnchor),
    threeTileView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyView.topAnchor),
    threeTileView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyView.bottomAnchor) 
])
```

Comment: I'm going to be adding these subviews dynamically though, so is this not possible? Does auto-layout = interface builder?

Comment: use auto-layout in xib/ custom class  of the tableCell , and if you want to use frame-layout use it inside **layoutSubviews** or better to also use auto-layout in code as it will enable you add views correctly at any time of cell life cycle

Comment: do you know how I accomplish this using auto-layout in code? I'm not very experienced but I appreciate the help. I essentially just want my threeTileView to occupy bodyView, its leading,trailing,top,bottom constraints to its superview.

Comment: Amaaaazzzing it worked! Thank you so much just spent about 3 hours on this.